# On duplicate key no funciona

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Llevo varios días intentando encontrar por qué en la misma tabla en la que hago la misma consulta con los mismos datos desde otro script funciona pero desde el que estoy ejecutando ahora mismo no funciona.

Es exactamente la misma consulta a la misma tabla, en un lado funciona perfectamente la consulta pero desde este no, he probado a hacer la consulta directamente en `Heidi` y `DBeaver` y en ninguno funciona pero ejecuto el script que iba bien y funciona, así que no entiendo que está pasando.

En resumen sólo hace `insert` pero nunca hace `update` a pesar de que las `key` se vean duplicadas.

Añado informacion, estos registros no deberian aparecer duplicados sino que la hora final deberia haberse actualizado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO rh_horastrabajadas_convivencia (id_usuario,id_departamento,fecha,horainicio,horafin,segundos,anio,mes,semana,dia)
                VALUES ($id_usuario,$id_departamento,'$fecha','$hora','00:00:00', $segundos, $anio,$mes,$semana,$dia)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE horaFin='$hora';";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías añadir la query que haces directamente en Dbeaver o similar, junto con el código de error que te devuelve.

Comment: Las bases de datos o los contextos pueden ser distintos... Aquí el problema, a mi juicio, es el código. Quizá has programado de un modo demasiado optimista. ¿Qué hay del control de errores en tu programa? Si lo hubieras implementado (invirtiendo 15 minutos más en la programación) te habrías ahorrado los varios días que llevas rompiéndote el coco y tendrías un programa maduro. Pues eso, controla los posibles errores, analiza lo que ocurre y si aún así no logras resolverlo nos dices. Moraleja: no seas optimista cuando programes, sé pesimista.

Comment: La cosa es que no tira errores por que funciona por asi decirlo, la cosa es que funciona el insert pero no el on update entonces de nada me sirve tener un control de errores para este caso concreto ya que la query hace pero no hace lo que yo quiero por asi decirlo, en resumen, no tira errores solo que en el caso del on update no lo hace, en su lugar inserta

Comment: @A.Cedano te respondo en el de antes que no te mencione

Comment: Ya, pero hay **errores a nivel de lógica**. Por poner un ejemplo, convendría aquí controlar el número de filas afectadas, para saber lo que ha ocurrido. La misma definición de *funciona*, muchos la interpretan erróneamente. ¿Qué significa que la consulta *funciona*, que no da error, o que cumple el objetivo para el cual fue creada: insertar, actualizar, borrar, etc? ¿Si una de esas consultas no afecta a ninguna fila por el motivo que sea, podemos decir que esa consulta *funciona* (a nivel de lógica)? Todos esos matices deben ser controlados en el código, cosa que no veo que haces.

Comment: @FcoJavierBalón no devuelve codigo de error por que la consulta se produce correctamente haciendo siempre el insert y nunca el update cosa que ahi el error, deberia hacer update pero devuelve insert